# Image won't load for tkinter program compiled with pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have a tkinter program that includes a .png image. I have compiled it using pyinstaller and the --onefile option so I have to access the image in a temporary location. This is the code I am using:

```py
def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception as e:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

```py
title = PhotoImage(file=resource_path("xgol.png"))
```

Here is my .spec file:

```py
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['XGols.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Sam\\OneDrive\\Computing\\Python Projects\\FootballPredict'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('Ball.ico', 'Ball.ico'), ('xgol.png', 'xgol.png')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='XGols',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True , icon='Ball.ico')
```

To compile the program I use:

```
pyinstaller --onefile XGols.spec
```

[This is the error that I get when I run the executable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYKqy.png)

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI61842\xgol.png": permission denied
```

I have tried running as administrator.

Comment: Have you checked that `xgol.png` exists in 
 `C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI61842` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.spec` file, additional data files should be listed like so:

```
datas=[('Ball.ico', '.'), ('xgol.png', '.')]
```

From [the documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html?highlight=add-data#adding-data-files):

> Each tuple has two values, both of which must be strings:
>
> - The first string specifies the file or files as they are in this system now.
> - The second specifies the name of the *folder* to contain the files at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

If file not found error:
Use MEIPASS2 instead of MEIPASS or vise versa and then \ instead of / if needed.

I think this way is a lot easier:

```
import os
import sys

def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS # after running the pyinstaller, if still looking
        # for temp folder then use sys._MEIPASS2 and if needed \\ instead of / for
        # all the path directories
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

Replace the

```
"folder_names/file_names"
```

with

```
resource_path("file_names/file_names")
```

in the Terminal type:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed  --icon=your_image.ico Your_File.py
```

or
in windows CMD (after installing the pyinstaller in cmd) type:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon=your_image.ico Your_File.py
```

The executable file will be available in a new folder called "dist".

now copy all the dependent folders into the "dist" folder

run the .exe and if all fine then zip the folder to share.

Delete Build and Dist folder along with any .spec files.

Replace the

```
resource_path("folder_names/file_names")
```

back to

```
"folder_names/file_names"
```

To go one step further and turn it into a setup installer file, use "inno setup" software.